# Select option in angular 2 not displaying proper value on selecting an option

Tags: angular

I have a form for which I am dynamically creating a select dropdown on add button. Following is my html code snippet:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of tmpWeeklyEvent;let index=index" class="col-xs-12 padding-left-right-0 clearfix">
    <select title="Select Country" class="form-control margin-top-5" [disabled]="scheduleStatus==null || scheduleStatus==undefined" [(ngModel)]="event.enumvalue" name="eventStatus">
        <option *ngFor="let item of scheduleStatus" value="{{item.EnumId}}">{{item.EnumString}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="increaseWeeklyEvent()">Add New Event</button>
```

`IncreaseWeeklyEvent()` just adds another event to the list:

```
increaseWeeklyEvent() {
    this.createWeekEvent();
}

createWeekEvent() {
        var newEvent = new TimeSchedule();
        var arrNewEvent = new Array<TimeSchedule>();

        if (this.scheduleStatus != null && this.scheduleStatus != undefined && this.scheduleStatus.length > 0)
        {
            newEvent.Time = "08:00";
            newEvent.enumvalue = this.scheduleStatus[0].EnumId;
            newEvent.Status = this.scheduleStatus[0].EnumString;

            this.tmpWeeklyEvent.push(newEvent);
        }
        else
        {
            this.toastr.error("No data found for Schedule Status Dropdown. Add/Edit will not work");
        }
    }
```

My problem is, as soon I click on Add button, the changed values in previous dropdowns return to default value. But on model, the changed value is preserved and even on HTML, I can see the correct value is binding to the select tag. So select tag displays some other string but binds to correct value as per selection in dropdown.

I tried replacing value in option tag with `[value]` and `[ngValue]` but same problem persists.

Please suggest where am I going wrong.

Comment: Please reproduce the issue in a plunker/stackblitz. I'm not even sure I understand the question. Is the template showing correct value or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this is a form. With forms, `name` attribute needs to be unique so that the fields are evaluated as separate fields and not one and the same. So if this is a form, your form value looks currently like

```
{
  "eventStatus": 1,
}
```

no matter how many fields you have, they all point to the one and same field. Whereas as you noticed your array has the correct values. This only affects the form. You can solve this by giving the select an unique `name`, which can be achieved using the index, so change your select to:

```html
<div *ngFor="let event of tmpWeeklyEvent; let index=index">
  <select  [(ngModel)]="event.enumvalue" name="eventStatus{{index}}">
  <!-- ... -->
```

and that should solve your issue.

Comment: Great, glad to hear! :) :)